# Grub Rescue afterinstall Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

I'm new to Linux. I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a external HDD. I followed all the instructions Installation ended without any error messages. When I reboot I end up at a Grub Rescue prompt. I have tried using ls on all my HDD's which return Unknown System. I've tried using the Boot-Repair to fix it but still end up at the Grub Rescue prompt.

Here is a copy of the Boot-Repair report.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23545612/

Any help appreciated.

Thanks 
Fabian

Comment: Boot-Repair says grub correctly reinstalled to sdd. Have you tried booting sdd. You have grub then installed everywhere. But it only should be installed to sdd. And your sda drive now only has logical partitions, so that copy of Windows cannot be booted from sda. Windows has to boot from a primary NTFS partition with boot flag & Windows boot files. You show the very old grub4dos often used by EasyBCD in sda5. Grub2 should not be installed to a partition even though that is the recommendation by  EasyBCD. And since you have multiple MBR, you would never install to a partition.